# Why application is failing to start for findAll method with Specifications?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb, spring-data

I'm using [spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb) in my boot app.

Repository class:

```java
//.. imports
class MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {
    Page<User> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
    Page<User> findByJoinedDateBetween(String startDate, String endDate, Pageable pageable);

    @EnableScan
    @EnableScanCount
    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

With above repository class, the application starts and returns expected output.

But, with below repository class setup (adding `JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>`):

```java
//.. imports
class MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>  {
    Page<User> findByName(String lastName, Pageable pageable);
    Page<User> findByJoinedDateBetween(String startDate, String endDate, Pageable pageable);

    @EnableScan
    @EnableScanCount
    Page<User> findAll(Specification<User> specs, Pageable pageable);
}
```

the app is failing to start with:

```java
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type User!
```

Am I not using it correctly? Is this because there is no support for `Specifications` at spring-data-dynamodb? Are `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories` and `JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>` compatible?

Comment: You don't need the `findAll` that is already part of the `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. If you define it yourself if will be processed by the part of Spring Data that generates a query from a `find` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I started with `repo.findAll(specs, pageable)` (without adding it to the Repository). When the error started coming up, I declared it in `MyRepository` to investigate the issue. Also, I think, this shouldn't be an issue as the without `JpaSpecificationExecutor` form works fine.

Comment: It works because `name` and `joinedDate` are fields in your `User`. Ther is no property `all`. As stated the method should just work and you shouldn't need to declare it (nor should you declare it) in your repository. Without adding the `findAll` did you get the same error or a different one? One thing you might try is to use `JpaRepository` instead of `PagingAndSortingRepository` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Just noticed the DynamoDB statement and `EnableDynamoDBRepositories`. That uses its own mechanism and afaik doesn't support `JpaSpecificationExecutor` (hence the error as it tries to create a query instead).

Comment: @M.Deinum By *works*, I meant the app is starting. But with `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, it won't start. Tried with `JpaRepository`, won't work. The [doc](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki) doesn't talk about compatibility with `EnableDynamoDBRepositories`

Comment: The dynamo stuff you are using isn't from the Spring team but a third party one, and is specially for DynamoDB. It isn't JPA so all that JPA stuff won't work. So unless there is a specific specification thing for DynamoDB in that library this simply won't work.